# nginx root directory as subdirectory in domain

Tags: nginx

I use nginx/1.10.1 with PHP 7 FPM.

I cloned phpmyadmin from Github to /var/www/vhosts/phpmyadmin

My domains are placed in
/var/www/vhosts/domain/domain.tld

Domain works with my nginx config fine but i want use this directory with phpmyadmin /var/www/vhosts/phpmyadmin use at domain.tld/phpmyadmin for example.

Here my current nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 default_server ssl;
    root /var/www/vhosts/domain/domain.tld;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain.tld www.domain.tld;

    location / {
            # return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location /phpmyadmin/ {
    root /var/www/vhosts/phpmyadmin;
            # return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    #        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /piwik {
    root /var/www/vhosts;
            # return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use either `root /var/www/vhosts;` or `alias /var/www/vhosts/phpmyadmin;` instead of `root /var/www/vhosts/phpmyadmin;` in your `location /phpmyadmin/` section.

`root` defines the document root for that section, and the URI is appended after that when looking for resource. So, in your case, nginx looks up for `/var/www/vhosts/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/index.php` when you try to get `http://www.domain.tld/phpmyadmin/` URL.

`alias` is different, it removes the part from URI that matches the `location` section where it is defined.